# Javascript Dynamic Variable (Random number added)

Tags: javascript, variables, random, dynamic

How do I create a dynamic variable in Javascript?

For example, I have:

```html
var myAwesomeText = "Hello World!"
```

But now I want the varible MyAesomeText to have a random number attached to it every time the page is refreshed. So it would instead look like something like this:

```html
var myAwesomeText12345 = "Hello World!"
```

And most importantly, how do I call that that new random variable back once the random number has been assigned to it? (i.e: alert(???);)

I've tried something like this, but I'm going wrong with this somewhere.

```html
var myRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
var myVar = "MyAwesomeText" + myRnd;
str = myVar + ' = ' + '"Hello World!"';
eval(str);

alert(str);
```

Comment: you can create a string and use eval()

Comment: eval is dangerous when you don't trust the input, very useful otherwise

Comment: But not at all necessary in this case. It is inefficient as it needs a script to be parsed on the spot.

Comment: like .001ms slower? having to write window[var1] once rather than var1 is way more innefficient

Comment: If you think you need a dynamic variable, you're probably wrong. Use an array or object.

Comment: @lonewarrior556, That is not a fair comparison. The comparison is between `window[var1]` and `eval(var1)`. The second will launch the JIT compiler to parse `var1`. Not at all necessary. Also can have unexpected effects. Imagine that `MyAwesomeText` (cf. question) would have a `;`  in it? Many more interesting variations can happen. `window[var1]` is the way to do it.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you need this. This may be an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223202).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the variable via the `window` object:

```js
var myRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
var myVar = "MyAwesomeText" + myRnd;
window[myVar]  = "Hello World!";

alert(window[myVar]);
```

Don't use `eval` for this: it is slower and completely unnecessary for this problem. Also it can have unexpected side-effects if your `MyAwesomeText` has characters in it that have special meaning in JavaScript code, such as brackets, semi-colon, colon, comma, braces, ... etc.

Note that the notation `object['prop']` gives the same result as `object.prop`. Since global variables are created in the `window` object, you can access any variable via the `window.myvariable` notation.

Combining these two facts, you can access global variables that have a dynamic name with `window[dynamicVariableName]`.

Comment: or... alert(eval(myVar)); :)

Comment: Thanks guys! This works well. I will use this in the larger project and will see if I run into any problems!

Answer (score 0):

eval is the way to go

```
var num = 10;
var string = "var a"+num +"= 'hi'"
string
// "var a10= 'hi'"
eval(string)
a10
// 'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss one eval on the alert

```
var myRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
var myVar = "MyAwesomeText" + myRnd;
str = myVar + ' = ' + '"Hello World!"';
eval(str);

alert(eval(myVar));
```